# How to create an event into a group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm using Microsoft Graph API v1 with Administrator credentials via my software to create Events in a Group. However the response I get is a `403` with the following:

```json
{  
"error": {
         "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
         "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",    
         "innerError": {      
             "request-id": "c4754c79-5e3a-4f63-9f88-404100513796",      
             "date": "2018-07-11T10:11:27"    
         }
    }
}
```

on a `POST` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{idGroup}/events/`

I have checked all rights provided to the app via Azure AD and everything is fine (tokens, code and scope with `Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All`). The Group is also created, the users are added to it and the owner is the admin I use for the create request.

I have also tried on the Microsoft Graph API Explorer but i have the same error.

Yesterday morning the creation was possible but I think some rights were corrupted. Is anybody has got this problem before? How to fix it?

Comment: That is quite interesting. According to documentation your scopes should be enough too: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_events

Comment: I know, that's my problem. Have you hear about any limitation on this API ? (I have read about 429 error but that is not my issue). Also note that the DELETE, PATCH and GET request are all working fine, my only issue is with the POST one.

Comment: Let's see if someone from the team has an answer, they watch the microsoft-graph tag.

Comment: How are you obtaining the token? Are you using the Authorization Code or the Client Credentials OAuth Grant?

Comment: I do not think this is the problem, all other request are working and the POST request is not working on the API Graph Explorer. But I'm using the Authorization Code provided on my redirect URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days without any changes in the code the problem dissapeared. 
I am still not sure of what happened, anyway thanks guys !